# cv.glmnet vs glmnet

Tags: r, regression, cross-validation, regression-coefficients, glmnet

I'm using `glmnet` to fit a ridge regression model on some data and evaluate the model's test MSE. The lambda value I select is derived from cross-validation. I'm using the College dataset from ISLR2, predicting applications to each college.

I have tried the following two approaches, and while in theory I should have the same result, I don't and I'm not sure why.

### First way

- I use `cv.glmnet()` to perform cross validation on the data, extracting the lambda with the lowest validation MSE
- Then I fit a ridge regression model using `glmnet()` on the data with the previously computed lambda
- Predict response on the test data using the fitted model and compute the test MSE

```
# Perform the cross validation
cv.ridge <- cv.glmnet(model.matrix(Apps~.,train), train$Apps, alpha=0, nfold=100)
# Store the best lambda value
best.lambda <- cv.ridge$lambda.min

# Fit ridge regression model with that lambda
ridge.fit <- glmnet(model.matrix(Apps~.,train), train$Apps, alpha=0, lambda=best.lambda)

# Predict the test response 
pred.out <- predict(cv.ridge, newx = model.matrix(Apps~.,test), s=best.lambda)

# Compute test MSE
mean((pred.out- Y_test)^2)
>> 2206587
```

### Second Way

- Once again I use `cv.glmnet()` to perform cross validation on the data
- I then predict the response on the test data directly with the `cv.glmnet` object, using the lambda value with the lowest validation MSE
- Compute the test MSE

```
# Perform the cross validation
cv.ridge <- cv.glmnet(model.matrix(Apps~.,train), train$Apps, alpha=0, nfold=100)
# Store the best lambda value
best.lambda <- cv.ridge$lambda.min

# Predict the test response
pred.out <- predict(cv.ridge, newx = model.matrix(Apps~.,test), s=best.lambda)

# Compute test MSE
mean((pred.out- Y_test)^2)
>>> 2204831
```

Why do these two approaches have different test MSE's? The only difference between the two ways is that in the second way I use the `cv.glmnet` object instead of the `glmnet` object in the `predict()` call.

I checked the coefficients of the models and they are not the same either.

```
# Coefficients from the glmnet() call on the specified lambda
coef(ridge.fit)

# Coefficients of the cv.glmnet() call given the same specified lambda
predict(cv.ridge, type='coefficients', s=best.lambda)
```

[image]

The coefficients are slightly different. Which I guess is why the test MSE's differ. But I'm not sure why this should be the case.

In both ways, since the lambda constraint specified is identical and the data used to fit the model is identical, shouldn't the resulting two ridge regression models be the same?

### Follow up :

I have tried setting the `s` parameter in the `predict` call but that doesn't seem to work either.

`cv.ridge` MSE :

```
# Fit cross-validated ridge regression model
cv.ridge <- cv.glmnet(model.matrix(Apps~.,College), College$Apps, alpha=0, nfold=100)
# Make prediction using lambda that minimizes cross-val MSE
pred.out <- predict(cv.ridge, model.matrix(Apps~.,College), s="lambda.min")
# Compute MSE
mean((pred.out- College$Apps)^2)
>> 1358455
```

`glmnet` way :

```
# Explicitly fit a ridge regression model on the same data using the previously computed lambda that minimizes CV mse
ridge.fit <- glmnet(model.matrix(Apps~.,College), College$Apps, alpha=0, lambda=cv.ridge$lambda.min)
# Make prediction 
pred.out <- predict(ridge.fit, model.matrix(Apps~.,College))
# Compute MSE
mean((pred.out- College$Apps)^2)
>> 1359837
```

The issue persists.

Note that in the `glmnet` way I didn't set any `s` parameter since the provided `glmnet` object only contains the fitted model with the lambda which minimizes CV MSE. The same lambda value used when the `cv.ridge` object does the prediction as well.

Setting `s='lambda.min'` doesn't change the result either.

Comment: +1 I think this is an outstanding example of a software-heavy question that is squarely on-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

`cv.glmnet` returns an object of type `cv.glmnet` (using dots in class names is asking for trouble with method dispatching, but this does not seem to be the problem here), which has overwritten methods for `predict` and `coef`, namely `predict.cv.glmnet` and `coef.cv.glmnet`. When you read their docs with

```
> ?coef.cv.glmnet
> ?predict.cv.glmnet
```

you will notice that they have an option `s` for specifying the lambda used. The coefficients seen in your question refer to `s="lambda.1se"`. Set it to `s="lambda.min"`, and the result is identical with your model trained with `lambda.min`:

```
> cv.ridge <- cv.glmnet(model.matrix(Apps~.,College), College$Apps, alpha=0, nfold=100)
> coef(cv.ridge, s="lambda.min")
19 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                        1
(Intercept) -1.468326e+03
(Intercept)  .           
PrivateYes  -5.278781e+02
Accept       1.004588e+00
...
> pred.out <- predict(cv.ridge, model.matrix(Apps~.,College), s="lambda.min")
> mean((pred.out- College$Apps)^2)
[1] 1358455
```

Remark: What do your data sets `train` and  `test` contain? Apparently something different from `College` because your MSE and coefficients are different.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! However changing the `s` parameter doesn't seem to resolve the issue

When i manually fit a ridge regression model using the minimum lambda value : 
`ridge.fit <- glmnet(model.matrix(Apps~.,College), College$Apps, alpha=0, lambda=cv.ridge$lambda.min)`

Then predict on the data : 
`pred.out <- predict(ridge.fit, model.matrix(Apps~.,College))`

the test MSE is `1359837` which differs from the `cv.glmnet` way. In the `predict` call for the ridge model I have also tried specifying the `s` parameter to `lambda.min` as well but it has no effect on the result.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, in part, about numerical accuracy. The `thresh` argument of [glmnet](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/glmnet/versions/4.1-4/topics/glmnet) controls the convergence threshold of the gradient descent algorithm used to fit the model. According to the documentation, the optimization stops when

> the maximum change in the objective after any coefficient update is less than thresh times the null deviance.

For gaussian models the deviance is mean squared error. For this particular example, the outcome is number of applications received by US colleges in 1995, so the null deviance is rather high: it's on the same order as the mean squared errors reported in the question, ie., on the order of 1,000,000.

Let's vary the threshold to demonstrate how the difference between the two fitted models gets smaller as we require a more accurate solution. (Full R code listing is attached at the end.)

```r
# null deviance on the original scale
mean((y - mean(y))^2)
#> [1] 14959182

# `abs_mse_diff` is the absolute difference in MSE between the cv.glmnet and glmnet models

abs_mse_diff(x, y, thresh = 1e-7)
#> [1] 1101.85
abs_mse_diff(x, y, thresh = 1e-8)
#> [1] 517.3258
abs_mse_diff(x, y, thresh = 1e-9)
#> [1] 113.6585
abs_mse_diff(x, y, thresh = 1e-10)
#> [1] 14.41409
```

The final `cv.glmnet` object is fitted to the full dataset, so there must be another source of randomness to obtain two numerically different solutions. However, they are "equivalent" within the precision specified by `thresh`. If you transform the response `y` to have unit scale, the difference in MSE between the `cv.glmnet` and the `glmnet` solutions is much smaller.

---

```r
library("glmnet")
library("tidyverse")

mse <- function(actual, predicted) {
  mean((actual - predicted)^2)
}

abs_mse_diff <- function(x, y, ...) {
  cv.ridge <- cv.glmnet(
    x, y,
    alpha = 0,
    ...
  )
  ridge.fit <- glmnet(
    x, y,
    alpha = 0,
    lambda = cv.ridge$lambda.min,
    ...
  )

  abs(
    mse(y, predict(cv.ridge, x, s = "lambda.min"))
    - mse(y, predict(ridge.fit, x))
  )
}

data(College, package = "ISLR2")

College <- College %>%
  select(where(is.numeric)) %>%
  select(Apps, everything())

College <- as.matrix(College)

x <- College[, -1]
y <- College[, 1]

# null deviance on the original scale
mean((y - mean(y))^2)

abs_mse_diff(x, y, thresh = 1e-7)
abs_mse_diff(x, y, thresh = 1e-8)
abs_mse_diff(x, y, thresh = 1e-9)
abs_mse_diff(x, y, thresh = 1e-10)

y <- scale(y, center = FALSE, scale = TRUE)

# null deviance after scaling the response
mean((y - mean(y))^2)

abs_mse_diff(x, y, thresh = 1e-7)
abs_mse_diff(x, y, thresh = 1e-8)
abs_mse_diff(x, y, thresh = 1e-9)
abs_mse_diff(x, y, thresh = 1e-10)
```